# Como remover ícone de validação required HTML5

Tags: html, html5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como remover este ícone marcado acima na imagem?

Comment: Retira o `required` e faça sua própria validação.

Comment: Utilizando o proprio required teria como retirar o icone?

Comment: @HappyBR não. O suporte a styling das mensagens de validação foi retirado do Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293209

Comment: Muito obrigado caro colega de programação! :D desta eu nao sabia :)

Comment: @HappyBR É sempre um prazer ajudar. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o que o **@OnoSendai** respondeu nos comentários, o suporte para estilizar as validações no Chrome não está mais disponível.

Fonte:https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293209